# Proving $P$ $\implies$ $Q$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I was wondering about this form of logical proof in the book: Programming in the 1990s, by Edward Cohen.

To prove $P \implies Q$, the author uses this sequence:

\begin{align*}
  Q \\
  \equiv\langle\text{Assuming P}\rangle \\
  true
\end{align*}

Could someone explain what’s the thought behind it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an "equational-style" proof, to prove a formula $A$ amounts to prove $A \equiv \text {true}$.

See David Gries & Fred Schneider, [A Logical Approach to Discrete Mathematics (Springer, 1993)](https://books.google.it/books?id=103UBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA72) for a more clear explanation.

See page 72, the:

> **(Extended) Deduction Theorem**:
>
> > if adding $P_1, \ldots P_n$ as axioms we are able to prove $Q$, then $P_1 \land \ldots \land P_n \Rightarrow Q$ is a theorem.

---

How to apply it to your proof ?

We have an assumption $P$ and we prove - under that assumption - that $Q \equiv \top$ [using $\top$ for $\text {true}$].

Using the deduction Theorem, we conclude with $P \Rightarrow (Q \equiv \top)$.

Then we need the **Distributivity law of** $\Rightarrow$ **over** $\equiv$:

> $(P \Rightarrow (Q \equiv R)) \equiv ((P \Rightarrow Q) \equiv (P \Rightarrow R))$.

With $\top$ in place of $R$, our formula above becomes: $(P \Rightarrow Q) \equiv (P \Rightarrow \top)$.

But $P \Rightarrow \top$ is $\top$; thus, we have arrived at:

> > $(P \Rightarrow Q) \equiv \top$

and this means that $P \Rightarrow Q$ is a theorem.

Comment: Thank you. What is the role of adding P as an assumption? How does it help in showing Q equivales true ?

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation !

Comment: @F.Zer - you are welcome :-)